# Fractional Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let us define the fractional Sobolev space
$$
W_{0}^{s,p}(\Omega):=\{u\in W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N):u=0\text{ on }\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega\},
$$
where
$$
||u||_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)}:=||u||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)}+||\frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^\frac{N+ps}{p}}||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^N)}<\infty.
$$

Now we define the space
$$
V_{0}^{s,p}(\Omega):=\overline{\{C_{c}^\infty(\Omega):||u||_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)}\}}.
$$

Are the two spaces $W_0^{s,p}(\Omega)$ and $V_{0}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ same for $0<s<1$ and $p>2$?

Can somebody kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: No because the $W_0^{s,p}(\Omega)$ functions need not be smooth.

Comment: Why functions in $V_0^{s,p}(\Omega)$ are smooth?

Comment: because they are contained in $C_c^{\infty}$

Comment: But it is the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, so they need not have compact support.

Comment: yeah but they are still smooth

Comment: See the characteristic function $1_{\Omega}$ belong to $V_0^{s,p}(\Omega)$ which is not smooth.